# iOS not playing html5 video after user gesture in JavaScript async function

Tags: javascript, ios, video, async-await, html5-video

I would like to play a HTML5 video in an async function, as a handler for the `click` event, but iOS returns a `NotAllowedError - The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`. All other browsers and operating systems play the video without error.

The video is visible on the page and works when the URL is directly entered. The `playsinline` option is added. I would not like to mute the video. The iOS environment is Safari on iOS 12, and the problem can also be reproduced on Safari iOS 11.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
async function StartButton_Click() {
    await doSomething();
    document.querySelector("#myvideo").play();
}
document.getElementById("startbutton").onclick = StartButton_Click;
```

The `await` statement is included because I want `doSomething()` to complete before the video starts.

`#myvideo` and `#startbutton` are all defined in the HTML. Specifically, `#myvideo` is as follows:

```
<video id="myvideo" preload="auto" src="video.mp4" playsinline></video>
```

I expect the video to play when the `#startbutton` is clicked, because iOS policy states that the video can play on user gesture. However, the error stated above is indicated in the console. Even though the handler is an `async` function, the video should still play because it still is a direct result of a user gesture.

How shall I modify this code for it to play on iOS Safari?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, video/audio requires users gestures to call their functions. But the problem here is that user gestures do not propagate with promises, settimeout, etc. This functionality was added in chrome 72 (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/nic72?hl=ja#user-activation) but in safari/IOS is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself. My solution for any latecomers to this thread was to use the initial gesture to play then immediately pause the video/audio:

```js
async function startButtonClick() {
   const myVid = document.querySelector("#myvideo");
   myVid.play();
   myVid.pause()
   await doSomething();
   myVid.play();
}
document.getElementById("startbutton").onclick = startButtonClick;
```

You could call `myVid.play()` [as a promise](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise) and ensure you catch the play to then pause before any playback.